# How do I rebase this NDP per capita data?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, gdp

So i got two different data sets that I want to put together, one is from 2004-05 to 2014-15 with the base year 2004-05 and the other one is 2011-12 to 2021-22 with base year 2011-12. I have also found the WPI index for both 2004-05 and 2011-12 that they are using.

I would like to use an WPI index that cover all of these years so I could put these two series together. I hope one of you guys knows how I should proceed! Many thanks.

EDIT: Links to data:
NDP per capita in constant prices
https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/PublicationsView.aspx?id=21413

WPI series
https://eaindustry.nic.in/download_data_0405.asp